# Calling a webservice repeatedly and export data

Tags: json, csv

I have a webservice which accepts a parameter and gives back result in a JSON message format.

http://portLocation/Company/WebService.asmx/Operation?parameter1=XX

My objective is to repeatedly call this webservice with the parameters in a CSV File.

What would be the ideal way to do it.

Comment: Do you mean, repetitively or recursively?

Write a console app to read the contents of the .csv file in a loop, calling the webservice each time.

Comment: That's right- repeatedly. I have updated the question.

Comment: If there any utility to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple working concept for C#.

You'll need to adjust it for your needs.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    string datafile = "data.csv";
    StringBuilder sbUrl = new StringBuilder("http://portLocation/Company/WebService.asmx/Operation");
    List<string> fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(datafile).ToList();

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        foreach (string item in fileContents)
        {
            string[] data = item.Split(',');
            sbUrl.AppendFormat("?parameter1={0}", data[0]);
            sbUrl.AppendFormat("&parameter2={0}", data[1]);
            sbUrl.AppendFormat("&parameter3={0}", data[2]);
            sbUrl.AppendFormat("&parameter4={0}", data[3]);
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(sbUrl.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```